# Database Reference Image Upload Wrong filename stored

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am teaching myself codeigniter so I used the image uploading class with storing the name in SQL and storing the image on a folder in the server. When you call the name from the server it will display from the file.

So that works fine, but I was curious on overwriting images so I checked the codeignter documentation on uploading files and they have a encrypt_file file function. So that would fix a overwrite issue, well now since I used it the file name that is stored in my database is the original file while, the image that is stored in my folder on the server has a encrypted file name, so there for the photo does no display.

I have went through codeigniter's documentation, trying to load another filename variable and so on. I tried also initializing the config each time also.

The controller the Library Upload is auto.

```
if($this->form_validation->run()=== FALSE)  {

$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
else{
        //Upload image

$config['upload_path'] = 'assets/images/posts';
$config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['encrypt_name']         = TRUE; //TURN ON
$config['max_size']             = 0;
$config['max_width']            = 0;
$config['max_height']           = 0;


$this->upload->initialize($config);



if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
$errors = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
$post_image = 'noimage.jpg';

}else {
$data = array('upload_data' =>$this->upload->data());
$post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

}

   $this->Post_Model->create_post($post_image);
    redirect('http://localhost/CI/');
}

}
```

MODEL

```
public function create_post($post_image){

$slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'));

$data=array('title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug' => $slug,
            'body' => $this->input->post('body'),
            'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
            'post_image' =>$post_image

);
```

form

```
<img src="assets/images/posts/<?php  echo $post['post_image'];?>">
```

Comment: what is your goal? to upload the same image, but under a different name? Are you storing the image path in a database to retrieve it later together with a e.g. news article?

Comment: @Vickel I want to be able to store images without the risk of overwriting the same image. I want to be able to retrieve the file as a blog post or a user profile photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Add the following configuration line of code to avoide overwrite `$config['overwrite'] = false`

Second, Give actual values to `max_size`, `max_width` and `max_height` not zero

```
$config['max_size']     = 1000;
$config['max_width']    = 430;
$config['max_height']   = 430;
$config['overwrite']    = false;
```

And where the file is uploading do some changes

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
  $errors = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
  $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
}else {
  $data = $this->upload->data();
  $post_image = $data['file_name'];

}
```

Comment: This worked, I think removing the array from my file fixed the issue I had before. So now the encrypt file works and saved the correct image name in both places. Thanks.